# How to check if the next or last value in an expression exists in java

Tags: java, if-statement, cancellation

Hello so what I am working on is how to check if a number for instance 10 and look at the next number which would be 11 and the number before 10, 9 and then to cancel out those numbers and return false.

```
public static boolean continue_sequence(int x, int y){

    if(x >= 0 && y == -1 ){
        return false;
    }
    // above is separate check that works below is the one I am trying to fix
    else if(x >= 0 && y += 1 || y -= 1){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;    
    }
}
```

here is what the output looks like for a redundant case
`U U Testing combination:21
U Ui Testing combination:22
U U2 Testing combination:23`

These are all redundant and can be replaced with one letter for example combination 23 can be replaced with a single Ui which has already been tested prior to these tests because the sequence length gets longer over time because there are 18 different instances (like U R L B' B2 and so on).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but are you looking for something like `else if(x >= 0 && Math.abs(x-y) == 1)`?

Comment: what you want to do at all ?!

Comment: im trying to get rid of numbers that come sequentially on after another so like 9,10,11, I wouldn't want any numbers in order. instead something like 9,12,16. does that help @Zircon ?

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber , please edit your question to include your desired output about sequential numbers.  Thanks.

Comment: I have a number combination tester and it goes through a whole bunch of numbers but I want to avoid sequential numbers, so like 8,9,10 because those could be cancelled out with 8,9 for example because these numbers have other properties and those properties are redundant and can be reduced to 2 numbers instead of 3. so avoiding sequential numbers is what I want to do @MohammadRezaKhatami

Comment: `+=` and `-=` updates the value of `y`. Don't do that.

Comment: ok @Andreas I won't :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean continue_sequence(int x, int y){

    if(x >= 0 && y == -1 ){
        return false;
    }
    // This if statement checks if x greater than 0 which our base condition,
    // second part "((x+1) == y || (x-1) == y)" checks x is sequential to the y    
    else if(x >= 0 && ((x+1) == y || (x-1) == y))
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
```

}

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you added an explanation _why_ your code example solves OP's problem.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks for the advice, I added brief comment

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return Math.abs(x-y) == 1

```
public static boolean continue_sequence(int x, int y){

        if(x >= 0 && y == -1 ){
            return false;
        }

        // above is separate check that works below is the one I am trying to fix
        return Math.abs(x-y) == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you can do this

```
if((x+1 == y) || (x-1 == y)) // x and y are sequential numbers.
    return false;
else // something else.
```

so if you pass 9,10 as x,y, then statement will be false.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    else if(x >= 0 && ( y += 1 || y -= 1))
```

try this